# SQL Server Database's Table's extension

Tags: sql-server

> What is extension of table in SQL Server ??

if we are creating table in SQL Server and I want to see path where these tables are located ? If *yes* , can anyone give me path .
Thank You .

Comment: Path? Are you trying to find a table instance on the HD?

Comment: yes, so i can see an extension of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to know the extension of the table?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Within a SQL Server database, the fully qualified table name is [Server Name].[Database Name].[Schema Name].[Table Name]

Tables are not considered files on disk.  They are stored in a database container file and the database software manages the storage within the database file.  Tables do not have a 'Path' in the traditional file sense, but the database does.

The database file is not person readable so do not bother to open in a text editor.  Doing so will likely corrupt the file.  Database file management tasks should only be handled through the database directly.  The database files cannot be safely copied to other locations or used as a backup.  There are specific processes to accomplish those tasks.  I recommend you hire a professional DBA if that is what you want to do.

Comment: I was just want to know  , How SQL server stores table in file system !  So if it stores tables in File System then may be possible those tables having extension too. 
But now i got cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Tables and indexes are stored in filegroups, not files directly. Each filegroup may contain several files. To query which table is in which filegroup, you can use:

```
select so.name, sfg.name
from sys.sysobjects so, sys.indexes si, sys.filegroups sfg
where si.data_space_id = sfg.data_space_id
and so.id = si.object_id
```

and to list the files for filegroups

```
select * from sys.sysfiles
```